# Unable to send a text message

Tags: sms

When I try to send a text message why does it go to drafts? And I still cant send the message even from drafts.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you actually did type up your message, but hit the back key by accident, or, did not supply the number for the intended person to receive your text, which gets saved in drafts.

When you go into Messaging, you should see "(Draft)" by the message, go into that message and there should be a 'Send' button beside the text entry box where you compose the message, tap that, it should go straight away.

Try it and let us know how that goes for you. :)